# Splitting a dataframe into multiple dataframes based on the column name in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with 557 columns which i want to split into multiple dataframes of different column lengths. I try to explain below what i would like to achieve with a smaller dataframe.

my dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(row.names = c("x","y","z"),
                 "a" = c(2844.8,10232.5,20150.6),
                 "b" = c(1430.9,29263.6,26334.5),
                 "c" = c(906.2,6019.1,6848.6),
                 "REG01" = c(1871.0,69618.7,45032.2),
                 "d" = c(2106.0,29929.6,58626.1),
                 "e" = c(1818.8,232371.1,42713.6),
                 "REG02" = c(1364.5,57561.7,20656.4),
                 "f" = c(520.4,46754.9,9036.9),
                 "REG03" = c(1821.4,43862.3,51876.1))

> df

        a       b       c   REG01       d        e    REG02        f   REG03
x  2844.8  1430.9   906.2  1871.0  2106.0   1818.8   1364.5    520.4  1821.4
y 10232.5 29263.6  6019.1 69618.7 29929.6 232371.1  57561.7  46754.9 43862.3
z 20150.6 26334.5  6848.6 45032.2 58626.1  42713.6  20656.4   9036.9 51876.1
```

Desired output - a list of 3 dataframes that looks like this:

```
> df.list[[1]]

        a       b       c   REG01       
x  2844.8  1430.9   906.2  1871.0  
y 10232.5 29263.6  6019.1 69618.7 
z 20150.6 26334.5  6848.6 45032.2 

> df.list[[2]]

         d        e    REG02
x   2106.0   1818.8   1364.5
y  29929.6 232371.1  57561.7
z  58626.1  42713.6  20656.4

> df.list[[3]]

      f     REG03
x 520.4    1821.4
y 46754.9 43862.3
z 9036.9  51876.1
```

I'm really struggling to know where to start as the resultant dataframes will be different sizes, the columns to split at are different names, and given my actual data is much larger (my result would be 44 dataframes) I can't explicitly reference the col names (although they do all start REG and are followed by 2 digits).

Thanks for any suggestions you may have

Comment: Could you please `dput` the data frame (`df`) so it's easier to copy-paste. Thanks

Comment: (1) build a list of column names, using e.g. `grep` and `c`, it should be like `col_names` where `col_names[[1L]]` is `c('a', 'b', 'c', 'REG01')`. Hopefully there's a pretty clear pattern & `col_names` can be constructed somewhat cleanly. (2) use `df.list = lapply(col_names, function(cols) df[cols])`. Beyond that, we would need a representative reproducible subset of your data to help further -- as Valeri mentioned, `dput` is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `split.default`

```
split.default(df, c(0, cumsum(grepl("^REG", names(df)[-ncol(df)]))))

$`0`
        a       b      c   REG01
x  2844.8  1430.9  906.2  1871.0
y 10232.5 29263.6 6019.1 69618.7
z 20150.6 26334.5 6848.6 45032.2

$`1`
        d        e   REG02
x  2106.0   1818.8  1364.5
y 29929.6 232371.1 57561.7
z 58626.1  42713.6 20656.4

$`2`
        f   REG03
x   520.4  1821.4
y 46754.9 43862.3
z  9036.9 51876.1
```

Comment: `tmp <- startsWith(names(df1), prefix = "REG"); split.default(df1, cumsum(tmp) - tmp)` is a second option.

Comment: Can you explain how `split.default` is different from `split`? I  couldn't get my answer to work without the double transpose `t()`

Comment: @DanielO what do you mean with unable to make your answer work?. `split ` does it accross the rows while `split.default` is across the columns. If you use `t` then you will mix datatypes. ie if there were some characters, then the numeric will be coerced to character, and we do not want that

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did not know that `split.default` existed or I certainly would have used it in my answer. The name is not exactly descriptive.

Comment: @DanielO not really. You could still use `lapply`. In your case, you could do: `lapply(split(names(df),cumsum(c(1,grepl("REG",colnames(df))))[1:ncol(df)]),function(x)df[x])`. Note that no  `t` was used

Comment: @Onyambu that's pretty smart passing the names in instead of the data. Thanks for the lessons

Answer (score 1):

in base-R

```
lapply(split( as.data.frame(t(df)), cumsum(c(1,grepl("REG",colnames(df))))[1:ncol(df)]),t)
```

gives

```
$`1`
        a       b      c   REG01
x  2844.8  1430.9  906.2  1871.0
y 10232.5 29263.6 6019.1 69618.7
z 20150.6 26334.5 6848.6 45032.2

$`2`
        d        e   REG02
x  2106.0   1818.8  1364.5
y 29929.6 232371.1 57561.7
z 58626.1  42713.6 20656.4

$`3`
        f   REG03
x   520.4  1821.4
y 46754.9 43862.3
z  9036.9 51876.1
```